# Возвращаем исходные настройки флешки в DiskPart

Tags: windows, диск, diskpart

Переустанавливал windows с флешки, делал по инструкции как [здесь](http://user-life.ru/kak-sdelat-samomu/kak-ustanovit-windows-s-fleshki.html)

Всё прекрасно переустановилась, работает и т.д.

Вопрос заключается в том, что флешку теперь распознает как диск, как вернуть её настройки ?

Answer (score 1):

Отформатируйте в нужную Вам файловую систему и используйте как раньше.

Comment: Но она всё ещё видна в биосе

Comment: "Но она всё ещё видна в биосе" - Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: То, что я всё ещё могу выбрать флешку в биосе как загрузочный диск

Comment: Эти вещи никак не связаны. Попробуйте вставить любую другую флешку, и вы также сможете выбрать ее в биос как загрузочный диск.

Comment: Тогда зачем вообще нужны все эти манипуляции с DiskPart ?

Comment: Большого смысла в "манипуляциях" из статьи нет, так как после создания раздела NTFS на флешку записывается iso. Все эти "манипуляции" никак не связаны с отображением в флешки в boot menu вашего bios. Читайте документацию к diskpart, документацию по файловым системам и bios, или правильно сформулируйте вопрос.